# Finding winner (greater number) out of all combinations in pandas

Tags: pandas, list, tuples, combinations, python-itertools

So my `fd.shape (105,4)`

```
fd.head()
                  Ccom           Wcom              Lcom         Dcom
 (A1, A2)  (82.0, 19.0)   (78.0, 99.0)  (1100.0, 9520.0)   (3.0, 3.0)
 (A1, A3)  (82.0, 25.0)   (78.0, 42.0)  (1100.0, 1700.0)   (3.0, 7.0)
 (A1, A4)  (82.0, 93.0)   (78.0, 37.0)  (1100.0, 1700.0)   (3.0, 7.0)
 (A1, A5)   (82.0, 9.2)   (78.0, 0.44)   (1100.0, 510.0)   (3.0, 7.0)
 (A1, A6)  (82.0, 52.0)  (78.0, 0.042)  (1100.0, 1100.0)  (3.0, 17.2)
```

Has all possible combinations from a df. Now I want to find winner (greater number) from each cell/combination and keep count of the wins for that An number.
Output should be something like this:

```
      Wins
A1     34
A2     44
A3     53
A4     76 .... and so on till last row
A15    43
```

This new dataframe basically keeps count of number of times A was greater than it's coombination.

Comment: It is a little bit unclear what you mean by winner. Could you elaborate? How do you calculate the column ```Wins```?

Comment: Whichever number is greater in the list wins. For example, first row (A1, A2) ; A1 is greater 1 time than A2 and A2 wins 2 time and it's a draw 1 time. So by end of first row, count of A1 wins column is 1; A2 is 2. By the end of whole df, Wins column should give the count of number of times it was greater than it's combination number(number with it in the list)

Comment: Are the values tuples or strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are tuples already skip this step. If the values are strings convert them to tuples

```
import ast
df = df.reset_index().applymap(ast.literal_eval).set_index('index')
```

Now compare the values and extract the columns from the tuple in the index. The output is not your expected output because your example input data is not your entire dataframe.

```
import numpy as np

(df.applymap(lambda x: np.sign(x[1] - x[0]))
   .apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1).drop(0.0, 1)
   .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values, index=x.name), axis=1)
   .reset_index(drop=True).T.sum(1).astype('int')
)
```

Out:

```
A1    9
A2    2
A3    2
A4    3
A5    1
A6    1
dtype: int64
```

---

### To reproduce this solution

Setup the dataframe with values as tuples

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import ast


a = """
                  Ccom           Wcom              Lcom         Dcom
 ('A1', 'A2')  (82.0, 19.0)   (78.0, 99.0)  (1100.0, 9520.0)   (3.0, 3.0)
 ('A1', 'A3')  (82.0, 25.0)   (78.0, 42.0)  (1100.0, 1700.0)   (3.0, 7.0)
 ('A1', 'A4')  (82.0, 93.0)   (78.0, 37.0)  (1100.0, 1700.0)   (3.0, 7.0)
 ('A1', 'A5')   (82.0, 9.2)   (78.0, 0.44)   (1100.0, 510.0)   (3.0, 7.0)
 ('A1', 'A6')  (82.0, 52.0)  (78.0, 0.042)  (1100.0, 1100.0)  (3.0, 17.2)"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(a), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
df = df.reset_index().applymap(ast.literal_eval).set_index('index')
```

Out:

```
                  Ccom           Wcom              Lcom         Dcom
index                                                               
(A1, A2)  (82.0, 19.0)   (78.0, 99.0)  (1100.0, 9520.0)   (3.0, 3.0)
(A1, A3)  (82.0, 25.0)   (78.0, 42.0)  (1100.0, 1700.0)   (3.0, 7.0)
(A1, A4)  (82.0, 93.0)   (78.0, 37.0)  (1100.0, 1700.0)   (3.0, 7.0)
(A1, A5)   (82.0, 9.2)   (78.0, 0.44)   (1100.0, 510.0)   (3.0, 7.0)
(A1, A6)  (82.0, 52.0)  (78.0, 0.042)  (1100.0, 1100.0)  (3.0, 17.2)
```

---

### Count wins and draws

To avoid doing computations twice the solution is slightly different. To count draws for both players you need two values. That's why columns `0.0` is selected twice with `df_counts[[0,0]]`.

```
df_counts = (df.applymap(lambda x: np.sign(x[1] - x[0]))
   .apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1))

# column 'wins'
df_result = (df_counts[[-1,1]].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values, index=x.name), axis=1)
   .reset_index(drop=True).T.sum(1).astype('int').to_frame('wins'))

# column 'draws'
df_result['draws'] = (df_counts[[0,0]].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values, index=x.name), axis=1)
   .reset_index(drop=True).T.sum(1).astype('int'))

df_result
```

Out:

```
    wins  draws
A1     9      2
A2     2      1
A3     2      0
A4     3      0
A5     1      0
A6     1      1
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. And for keeping count of draws as well (0.0) in seperate column?

Comment: `results['Draws'] = fd.applymap(lambda x: np.sign(x[1]-x[0])).apply(pd.Series.value_counts, axis=1).drop(1, 1).drop(-1,1).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values, index=x.name), axis=1).reset_index(drop=True).T.sum(1).astype('int')` This is what I'm trying. It's giving length of passed values is 1, index implies 2 error.

Comment: Your solution is nearly correct. I added this requirement to the solution with a short explanation.

Comment: Type Error: "Float_object is not subscriptable"

Comment: I tested the code without error. Which line causes the error?